# why wouldn't this selector work? JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, selector

I have a class name `active`
and in js I have something like this

```
var selectClass = active;
var a = $("'." + selectCLass + "'");
a.on('click', function(){})
```

When I do this, it would keep on giving me errors.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `active !== "active"` one is a String, the other one a variable.

Comment: Even though this may seem like a very simple question, it usually helps to post exactly what the error is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generated selector string has errors... make it like

```
var a = $("." + selectCLass);
```

Comment: words great!!! thx thx but why we don't need to add `''` inside the selector? usually it's like `$('.class')` but in this way it only looks something like `$(.class)` isn't it?

Comment: in code, `'.class'` is a string literal = `.class` ... if selectClass is a string with value `class`, then `"." + selectCLass` is a string = `.class` - `"'." + selectCLass + "'"` is a string = `'.class'` ... [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#String_literals)

Comment: @JaromandaX ah, right I totally need to get my head around this. thx txh